# SQL Server Reporting Service 2010 | Not working in Console app

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services

I want to list all the subscriptions made in the reporting server. For this I created a sample console application and added the reference of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll located in the

> %Program Files(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

But, when I am trying to create object of ReportingService2010 using the following

> ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010 r = new
>   ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010();

It won't allow me to create the object, and throws a compile time error

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ReportingService2010'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Which ddl's I am missing here please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a ReportViewer package that needs to be deployed (link below). Adding reference to the project from your development box may not be sufficient.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ReportingService2010 is not part of the reference Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.
You need to add a web refrence to your project.

Here is a great tutorial from Microsoft, it shows you how to add a web reference to the SQL Server Reporting Web Service:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169926.aspx

If you follow these steps you should be able to use ReportingService2010 like this:

```
ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
```